# About resetting the fonts

Tags: fonts, 16.10

I installed the tweak tool in my ubuntu to change the font size. When i installed it, fonts of my laptop get changed and it seems very ugly to see that. After that i uninstalled it (thinking the fonts will reset).
I want to recover my old font configuration.
Is there any command to reset those fonts.

Comment: install unity tweak tools again and get back to default fonts,  i think that their is a restore default button in unity tweak tools

Comment: i also tried that but there is no change in the fonts @SumeetDeshmukh